# Can a wifi device be inductively coupled to its remote antenna?

Tags: antenna, inductance, wifi, coupler

I’m developing an electronics device that will be towed underwater and which needs to transmit data to the surface.   Since RF works poorly underwater, I’m tying to extend the underwater device’s Wi-Fi antenna to the surface (about 50 ft) by coupling it across a pulley and am questioning whether this could be done by inductive or capacitive coupling.

A sketch that shows the underwater device, my inductor wrapped around an antenna wire is shown.  The antenna wire would have to move freely within the inductive field within the hollow core nylon cable used for towing.

[image: towed underwater device]

My EE/ham radio formulas are long forgotten but wondered if someone could point me to feasibility as well as design approaches to make an effective antenna which can be coupled electromagnetically rather than physically.

EDIT:  additional info.

1. Transmitting HD video buffered with processor such as raspberry pi.
2. Antenna wire- if I were coupling directly I would use a very thin low loss flexible coax with the terminal trimmed/deshielded for wavelength.   But not sure how to induce radio signal onto it.
3. Part of my inspiration for decoupled antennas came from several hacks for using GoPro underwater eg [link](https://www.theeminentcodfish.com/live-streaming-underwater-video/).

Comment: The fact that all that water's there is going to be a lot more of a problem.

Comment: If you have a cable why are you trying to do wireless?

Comment: it makes no sense to use wifi ... use much lower frequency

Comment: The weight of the towed equipment requires a pulley to be used in order to retrieve the equipment to the boat or to adjust distance from the boat.  Therefore the antenna wire needs to be physically disconnected from the towed equipment but electrically coupled.

Comment: @jsotola I could consider lower frequency but for what purpose?   I’m transmitting live HD video from underwater and likely need the bandwidth plus even low frequency rf loses all power within feet underwater.   So I need to get antenna above waterline to transmit.

Comment: @leeprevost lower frequencies penetrate water better ... your post says nothing about transmitting HD video

Comment: Use a trailing antenna cable, completely separated from the tow cable, with a floating bouy and antenna mounted on top.

Comment: What do you mean by 'antenna wire'?

Comment: If I were coupling this directly over the pulley, it would be a 50 ft section of low loss thin coax with the last section deshielded to expose center wire for the terminal antenna.   But am not sure how the inductive coupling works or if it works.

Comment: Part of my inspiration came from several hacks for using GoPro underwater eg https://www.theeminentcodfish.com/live-streaming-underwater-video/